# How to split a data file by a specific expression?

Tags: python, bash

I have a huge data file like this:

```
          1.2 BINARY:(  2,  3) A=     2.6     e=    0.9161 R=    4.7066
          1.2 BINARY:(  2,  4) A=     4.7     e=    0.9164 R=    8.9467
          1.2 BINARY:(  2,  5) A=     9.6     e=    0.9186 R=   18.3088
          1.2 BINARY:(  6,  7) A=     2.6     e=    0.8997 R=    4.6678
          1.2 BINARY:(  6,  8) A=     4.8     e=    0.8952 R=    8.8832
          1.2 BINARY:(  6,  9) A=     10.     e=    0.9036 R=   18.1821
          1.2 BINARY:( 10, 11) A=     2.6     e=    0.9152 R=    4.7108
          1.2 BINARY:( 10, 12) A=     4.7     e=    0.9175 R=    8.9469
          1.2 BINARY:( 10, 13) A=     9.5     e=    0.9249 R=   18.3082
          1.2 BINARY:( 14, 15) A=     2.7     e=    0.8687 R=    4.8092
          1.2 BINARY:( 14, 16) A=     4.9     e=    0.8530 R=    8.9601
          1.2 BINARY:( 14, 17) A=     10.     e=    0.8236 R=   18.2680
```

I want to split every line which includes `BINARY:(  2,  3)` in a separate file.
I know this syntax to split a file by suffixes of length N, but  it's not working for a specific text.

```
split -a –suffix-length=N filename outputfile
```

and I also know this: `sed -n '16224,16482 p' orig-data-file > new-file`, but for using the latter I have to know the exact number of lines which in my case the phrase `BINARY:(  2,  3)` is not repeated regularly. so, I cannot split  by number of lines.

Comment: So you want to create a separate file containing only the lines that have "BINARY:(  2,  3)" inside them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem from what your post that `grep` will do what you want. It will search the entire file for any occurrence of the search string.

```
grep '1.2 BINARY:(  2,  3)' data-file > new-file
```